# Kotlin: how to combine certain data in list

Tags: list, kotlin, collections

I want to process the crossday data(id = 1 and 2 or 3 and 4) with endTime and startTime in list, but some data were not crossday..... how would you approach this?

I already process to get data by this code.

```kotlin
    val grouped = oldListNewSleepData
            .groupBy { it.startTime }
            .flatMap { entry ->
                Timber.i("get sleep entry: $entry")
                listOf(
                    NewSleepData(id = entry.value.first().id,
                        startTime = entry.key ,
                        endTime = entry.value.maxBy { item -> item.endTime!!}?.endTime,
                        duration = entry.value.first { item -> item.duration != null }.duration,
                        activity = entry.value.first { item -> item.activity != null }.activity
                    )
                )
            }
            .filter {
                it.activity != null &&
                        (it.activity.contains("Sleep") || it.activity.contains("Awake"))
            }
```

this is data

```
[
    NewSleepData(id=1, startTime=2020-05-07T23:30:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-08T00:00:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=0.50), 
    NewSleepData(id=2, startTime=2020-05-08T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-08T08:30:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=8.50),
    //// merge above startTime and endTime
    NewSleepData(id=3, startTime=2020-05-09T22:47:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-10T00:00:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=1.22),
    NewSleepData(id=4, startTime=2020-05-10T00:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-10T08:43:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=8.72),
    //// merge above startTime and endTime
    NewSleepData(id=5, startTime=2020-05-11T00:50:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-11T08:30:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=7.67), 
    NewSleepData(id=6, startTime=2020-05-12T01:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-12T08:03:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=7.05),
    NewSleepData(id=7, startTime=2020-05-13T01:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-13T07:55:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=6.92),
    NewSleepData(id=8, startTime=2020-05-13T15:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-13T16:01:00.000Z, activity=LightSleep, duration=1.02),
    NewSleepData(id=9, startTime=2020-05-14T01:56:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-14T08:29:00.000Z, activity=LightSleep, duration=4.22), 
    NewSleepData(id=9, startTime=2020-05-14T02:05:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-14T07:49:00.000Z, activity=DeepSleep, duration=1.53),
    NewSleepData(id=9, startTime=2020-05-14T06:10:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-14T06:58:00.000Z, activity=Awake(during sleep cycle), duration=0.80),
    NewSleepData(id=10, startTime=2020-05-15T02:07:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-15T08:24:00.000Z, activity=LightSleep, duration=4.58),
    NewSleepData(id=10, startTime=2020-05-15T02:16:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-15T07:47:00.000Z, activity=DeepSleep, duration=1.70)
]
```

*Update
Sorry, I want to get this

```
[
    NewSleepData(id=1, startTime=2020-05-07T23:30:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-08T08:30:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=9.00)
    NewSleepData(id=3, startTime=2020-05-09T22:47:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-10T08:43:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=9.94)
    NewSleepData(id=5, startTime=2020-05-11T00:50:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-11T08:30:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=7.67), 
    NewSleepData(id=6, startTime=2020-05-12T01:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-12T08:03:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=7.05),
    NewSleepData(id=7, startTime=2020-05-13T01:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-13T07:55:00.000Z, activity=Sleep, duration=6.92),
    NewSleepData(id=8, startTime=2020-05-13T15:00:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-13T16:01:00.000Z, activity=LightSleep, duration=1.02),
    NewSleepData(id=9, startTime=2020-05-14T01:56:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-14T08:29:00.000Z, activity=LightSleep, duration=4.22), 
    NewSleepData(id=9, startTime=2020-05-14T02:05:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-14T07:49:00.000Z, activity=DeepSleep, duration=1.53),
    NewSleepData(id=9, startTime=2020-05-14T06:10:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-14T06:58:00.000Z, activity=Awake(during sleep cycle), duration=0.80),
    NewSleepData(id=10, startTime=2020-05-15T02:07:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-15T08:24:00.000Z, activity=LightSleep, duration=4.58),
    NewSleepData(id=10, startTime=2020-05-15T02:16:00.000Z, endTime=2020-05-15T07:47:00.000Z, activity=DeepSleep, duration=1.70)
]
```

Comment: Please, improve your question describing what are the constraints and what you want to achieve. It is not clear enough in my opinion.

Comment: @DiegoMarin Sorry, I have edited my question.